# n-way sort-merge-join algorithm efficiency

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting

is there an advantage of doing a n-way sort-merge-join vs doing 2-way sort-merge-joins sequentially?

is there a situation where 2-way joins might be more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: @NikunjBanka The 16-way merge in the standard Unix sort improves performance on large sorts by a factor of 4.  Is a factor of 4 performance improvement a good enough reason for you?

Answer (score 2):

An n-way merge join will require fewer passes through the data to finish sorting.  In the case of an external sort, the number of passes times the size of each pass is the amount of I/O that you have to do.  If your run time is bound by I/O, reducing I/O is definitely good.  For example as http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html points out, the standard Unix sort utility does 16 way merges for this reason.  Therefore in 1 pass, it does what would otherwise take 4 passes, which means that the whole sort is 4x as fast.

But a 2-way merge join is simpler to code and can get away with fewer comparisons.

Comment: Thank you for this, are there any 2-way joins (not necessarily merge-join) that might be more efficient that n-way merge join?

Comment: @emraldinho Fewer comparisons would be more efficient, right?